# How to read PPP$?

Tags: idiomatic-language

How to read PPP$ aloud?

Is it "purchasing power parity in US Dollar,"

or "purchasing power parity in terms of US Dollar,"

or ... ?

Comment: @SamBC This is not an economics question. I want to know how people read PPP$ in English language. Do they read it as PPP US dollars or ... or ... ?

Comment: I've edited the question to be clearer. You didn't say you wanted to know how it was read *aloud*. "How to read" something can have several meanings.

Comment: I have never encountered this acronym before. Even knowing what it stands for now, I find it terribly awkward to say in *any* form. To express it verbally I'd probably just say *purchasing power*. Note that I have no idea how you are getting *US Dollar* out of the $ symbol, which does not denote anything other than just *dollar*, devoid of any regional currency.

Comment: close-voters please explain your votes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any universally-agreed-upon way to say that aloud. It would depend on the audience and the circumstance - does the audience know what purchasing power parity is? Do they recognise the abbreviation PPP to refer to it?

In a context where people are very familiar, either of the following could be right:

> Dollars PPP
>   PPP in dollars

In a situation where people had no idea what it was at all, it might be:

> An amount of local currency with local purchasing power equivalent to the purchasing power of N dollars in the US.

Somewhere in between might be:

> Dollars equivalent (in terms of) purchasing power
>   Purchasing power equivalent in (terms of) dollars

But I don't think it's something you're going to get any sort of authoritative answer on, except possibly among economists.

Comment: So no more close-voting? I asked the same question on Economics and some people say it is off topic because it is more of a linguistic question.